# Mesh Not Moving Properly With Armature

Tags: mesh, armature

I've struggled so much to figure out why my dragon mesh moves with the armature, except the wings, which just get stuck in place and don't move with the rest of the mesh (it's all as one object and parented). Although, I'm not sure that the object and armature have been parented corrected with weights. Below is the link to my blender file. I really need help with this and anything would be appreciated :)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xQ7INOLt76DE6nL1QCeCdSvZ2hn__k66

Comment: I've tried opening the blend file but with no success. Based on the description of the problem you might have rigging problems. I've found the humane rigging blender tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3J-XN38EnhQ&list=PLE211C8C41F1AFBAB. This will help you a lot on understanding the problem at hand. Also consider giving a try to the blender cloud there is a lot of useful examples and tutorials. https://store.blender.org/product/membership/

Comment: Please avoid a link to  Google drive. See help centre.

Answer (score 1):

You should unclick the *Bone Envelopes* option of the *Armature* modifier of the mesh, then select the armature, <kbd>shift</kbd> select the mesh, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> to switch to *Weight Paint* mode, then select each bone and paint the mesh accordingly to the influence you want this bone to have on the mesh.

Or even delete the *Armature* modifier and reparent the mesh to the armature *With Automatic Weight* and then bring some corrections in *Weight Paint* mode...